# How to Create and Read Indexes Mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using .Net Driver version 2.4 and i'm unable to find a way to make sure for an index on a collection. i'm able to to do it via shell

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").ensureIndex({"Location.Coordinates":"2dsphere"});
```

i have seen people doing

```
collection.EnsureIndex(keys, options)
```

I can't Find the method with my current driver version.

**UPDATE**
I found the following code that works for creating the index

```
 var index = Builders<myType>.IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere("Location.Coordinates");
 collection.Indexes.CreateOne(index);
```

Now i Want to make sure if one index exists.I have this query that returns me indexes as BsonDocument but facing issues while deserializing that BsonDocument.
it returns following object in shell

```
 [
       {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "mydb.myCollection"
       }
    ]
```

I am using following class to deserialize this object

```
internal class MongoDbIndex
    {
        public int v { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public string ns { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<object,object> key { get; set; }

    }
```

having issues on key property because different indexes have different data types.

Comment: that's not available in driver version 2.4.3

Comment: that's legacy driver. for that i need to downgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I'm able to ensure Geo Index By doing following

```
var index = Builders<MyCollection>.IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere("Location.Coordinates");
db.MyCollection.Indexes.CreateOne(index);
```

by doing running this it will create the index for the first time, rest of the time it will not create a duplicate index if already exists.

`EnsureIndex` method is not available in latest version of mongodb C# Driver.